# Inner join is giving one result when it should give more

Tags: mysql

```
table1                               table2
id name logo                         id  name  value
1  a    asd                          1   a     2
2  b    asd                          2   a     3
3  c    asd                          3   b     4
```

Query:

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.logo,avg(table2.value) as average,
  count(table2.id) as no FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name 
    ORDER BY no
```

this code gives only one result than 2 results

Comment: Bad use of an aggregate without an appropriate GROUP BY - *include all non-aggregate columns in the GROUP BY*. Fix that and the problem should "fix itself". (SQL Server would simply - and rightly - reject this plan.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have no `GROUP BY` clause, try adding one.

```
SELECT  a.name,
        a.logo,
        AVG(b.value) avg_val,
        COUNT(*) no
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.name = b.name
GROUP   BY a.Name
ORDER   BY no
```

Answer (score 0):

FROM  [REFERENCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

*If you use a group function in a statement containing no 
GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.*

So Use Group By

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.logo,avg(table2.value) as average,
       count(table2.id) as no 

FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.name = table2.name 

GROUP BY table1.name
ORDER BY no
```

and you should be fine

SEE  [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26c7d/2)